# is it possible to make eclipse go back/forward function to work like ones in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

As being an IntelliJ IDEA user for 3 years and using eclipse past one year, I'm concerned about eclipse back\forward navigation, It seems that it remembers cursor position only in specific circumstances. As opposing, IntelliJ IDEA remembers every position you've clicked in every file, so back\forward working very natural. Is there a possibility to make eclipse's back\forward to work same as in IntelliJ IDEA? Also I'd like to have some other IDEA features in eclipse but this particular one is very distracting and annoying, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently managed in [bug 73224](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=73224) (and detailed in [bug 241811](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=241811)), since 2008.

For now, not much is coming out of it:

> It's hard to find the right amount of caret moves to put into the history.
>   You certainly don't want every caret move to end up in the history, otherwise the history quickly gets swamped with many little moves as soon as you e.g. start editing a method and move around with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> or just the arrow keys.
>
> I guess we would need some new heuristics to find "interesting" locations triggered by caret moves.

Comment: OT: I like the simple heuristic used by Emacs. Leaving a position by jumping to the beginning/end sets the mark, other moves do not. You can set it explicitly, too.